# Issue with display components after run program

Tags: c#, winforms

I have got issue with my program (written in C#.NET, Framework 4.5.2).  When I run it on my computer everything is OK but when I run it on another computer the components are not in right positions. This issue you can see on picture below. I do not know how I can solve this problem. Maybe it is caused by different display resolution? So this is the reason why I am writing. I will be appreciate for any clues. Thank you in advance.

[Image1](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Am6W4R8-Z5nehKcJm4KHpVIdubP5lA)

[Image2](https://1drv.ms/i/s!Am6W4R8-Z5nehKcIJP11LQlcGrqvBw)

Comment: There is a program built in to windows call `SnippingTool.exe` use that to capture screenshots instead of your phone. Also, try to upload your pictures using the built in tools on this website. Having 1 rep it will only generate links but a higher rep user will turn it in to a full image.

Comment: It's very hard to tell without seeing some code that shows how you lay out the controls. Suggest you update your question with that information. You can sometimes get unexpected layout results if a special font is used for development that's not on the target machine, or if the target machine is a retina display on a Mac running Windows or Widows emulation. There are many other causes that have to do with the code itself.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I know about softwer to capture. My problem with wrong  display appeared at work. So it is reason why I took the photos by phone. Unfortunately, I have got too less points to upload the pictures directly in this page. I will try to make better pictures. 
@Eric
Thank you for answer. Honestly, I use VS Community 2015. I do not know where is code of layout. I positione components by using propertis window. I have never had problem with display. I use my program only on Windows systems (workstation and laptop). I use standard fonts which are set at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. I added code below. It causes that my components are always in the same place.

this.general_viewDataGridView.Size = new Size(general_viewDataGridView.Size.Width, this.Size.Height - (gb_button .Location.Y + gb_button .Size.Height +50));